# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in webpack

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack

```
/src/assets/js/core.min.js

Module not found: Error: 
Can't resolve '../jquery' in 'C:\Users\mohammad\vue-webpack\src\assets\js'
 @ ./src/assets/js/core.min.js 62:67-90
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/Footer.vue
 @ ./src/Footer.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I have js files minimized in core.min.js.
I didn't show the code of the minimized js files because of the body number of characters limit.
Urls of all minimized js files imported are mentioned in the comments.

To view the full code of core.min.js check 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IYcH31j2lqh96ZlNgdXr6wnqrq2HAWCK/view

core.min.js

```
/**
 * @module       jQuery
 * @author       jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * @see          https://code.jquery.com/jquery/
 * @license      MIT (jquery.org/license)
 * @version      3.2.1
 */


/**
 * @module       jQuery Migrate
 * @author       jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * @see          https://code.jquery.com/jquery/
 * @license      MIT
 * @version      3.0.0
 */


/**
 * @module       jQuery Cookie Plugin
 * @see          https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 * @license      MIT
 */


/**
 * @module       Device.js
 * @see          https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js
 * @license      MIT
 */


/**
 * @module       jQuery resize event
 * @see          http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/
 * @license      MIT
 */


/**
 * @module       jQuery easing
 * @author       George McGinley Smith
 * @see          http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
 * @license      BSD
 * @version      1.4.0
 */

/**
 * @module       TouchSwipe
 * @see          https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin
 * @license      MIT
 * @version      1.6.18
 */


/**
 * @module       Popper.js
 * @author       Federico Zivolo
 * @see          https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js
 * @license      MIT
 * @version      1.14.3
 */


/**
 * @module       Bootstrap
 * @author       Twitter, Inc.
 * @see          http://getbootstrap.com
 * @license      MIT
 * @version      4.1.3
 */


/**
 * @module       Regula
 * @description  An annotation-based form-validation framework in Javascript
 * @license      BSD
 * @version      1.3.4
 * @copyright    Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com
 */


/**
 * @module       Form
 * @version      3.51
 * @author       M. Alsup
 * @see          {@link http://malsup.com/jquery/form}
 * @see          {@link https://github.com/jquery-form/form}
 * @license      MIT and GPL
 * @requires     module:jQuery
 */

/**
 * @module       RDInputLabel
 * @author       Evgeniy Gusarov
 * @license      MIT
 */


/**
 * @module       RD FilePicker
 * @author       Aleksey Patsurkovskiy
 * @version      1.0.2
 * @license      MIT
 * @link         http://cms.devoffice.com/coding-demo/mnemon1k/rd-filepicker/demo/
 */


/**
 * @module       Owl carousel
 * @version      2.2.1
 * @author       Bartosz Wojciechowski
 * @license      MIT
 */


/**
 * @module       Isotope PACKAGED
 * @license      GPLv3
 * @see          http://isotope.metafizzy.co
 * @version      2.2.2
 */


/**
 * @module       RD Navbar
 * @author       Evgeniy Gusarov
 * @see          https://ua.linkedin.com/pub/evgeniy-gusarov/8a/a40/54a
 * @version      2.2.5
 */


/**
 * @module       UIToTop
 * @author       Matt Varone
 * @see          http://www.mattvarone.com/web-design/uitotop-jquery-plugin/
 * @license      MIT
 */


/**
 * @module       Materianize Parallax
 * @see          http://materializecss.com/parallax-demo.html
 * @licesne      MIT
 */


/**
 * @module       Swiper
 * @description  Most modern mobile touch slider and framework with hardware accelerated transitions
 * @author       Vladimir Kharlampidi
 * @see          http://www.idangero.us/swiper/
 * @licesne      MIT
 * @version      4.1.0
 */




/**
 * @module       Lightgallery
 * @author       Sachin N
 * @see          http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/
 * @license      GPLv3
 * @version      1.6.2 - 2017-10-03
 */


/**
 * @module       WOW
 * @author       Matthieu Aussaguel
 * @license      MIT
 * @version      1.1.3
 */


/**
 * @module       PageTransition
 * @author       Roman Kravchuk (JeremyLuis)
 * @license      MIT
 * @version      1.1.3
 * @description  Smooth transition between pages
 * @requires     module:jQuery
 */


/**
 * @module       Select2
 * @see          https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/
 * @license      MIT
 * @version      3.5.4
 */


/**
 * @module       Slick
 * @author       Ken Wheeler
 * @see          http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick
 * @version      1.6.0
 */


/**
 * @module       Stepper
 * @version      3.0.8
 * @license      MIT
 * @link         http://classic.formstone.it/stepper/
 */


/**
 * @module CustomEvent polyfill
 */


/**
 * @module       MultiToggles
 * @author       ATOM
 * @license      MIT
 * @see          https://codepen.io/OXAYAZA/pen/eRbYjV
 * @version      2.0.0
 * @description  Allows you to use multiple toggles to switch class "active" on the target,
 *               itself and other toggles linked to the same target.
 */


/**
 * @module       RD Range
 * @author       Roman Kholiavko
 * @see          http://cms.devoffice.com/coding-demo/marathoner/rd-range/documentation
 * @version      1.0
 */


/**
 * @module       jQuery Mousewheel
 * @license      MIT
 * @version      3.1.13
 */

/**
 * @module       jQuery Mousewheel
 * @author       2014 Kelvin Luck & 2017-2018 Tuukka Pasanen
 * @see          http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
 * @license      Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL licenses.
 * @version      2.1.2-rc.1
 */


/**
 * @module  αUtil
 * @version v1.0.1
 * @desc    Service functions for α-modules
 * @author  OXAYAZA {@link https://github.com/OXAYAZA}
 * @license CC BY-SA 4.0 {@link https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}
 * @see     {@link https://www.linkedin.com/in/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2-166479165/}
 */

/**
 * @module   αCounter
 * @version  v0.1.1
 * @author   OXAYAZA {@link https://github.com/OXAYAZA}
 * @license  CC BY-SA 4.0 {@link https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}
 * @requires module:αUtil
 * @see      {@link https://oxayaza.page.link/gitHub_aCounters}
 */

/**
 * @module   αProgressCircle
 * @version  v0.1.1
 * @author   OXAYAZA {@link https://github.com/OXAYAZA}
 * @license  CC BY-SA 4.0 {@link https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}
 * @requires module:αUtil
 * @see      {@link https://oxayaza.page.link/gitHub_aCounters}
 */

/**
 * @module   αCountdown
 * @version  v0.1.1
 * @author   OXAYAZA {@link https://github.com/OXAYAZA}
 * @license  CC BY-SA 4.0 {@link https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}
 * @requires module:αUtil
 * @requires module:αProgressCircle
 * @see      {@link https://oxayaza.page.link/gitHub_aCounters}
 */
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {

          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000/*,
              mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'*/
            }
          }
        ]
      }

    ],

  },
  resolve: {

    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'

    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']

  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },

  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })


  ])
}
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import Header from './Header.vue';
import Home from './Home.vue';
import Footer from './Footer.vue';


Vue.component('app-header',Header);
Vue.component('app-home',Home);
Vue.component('app-footer',Footer);


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

I import core.min.js inside Footer.vue:

```
<!-- Page Footer-->
      <!-- Pre footer section-->
<template>

  <div>
    Test
  </div>  

</template>

<script>
  import "./assets/js/core.min.js";
</script>

export default {
    name: 'Footer'
  }
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <div class="page">

      <app-header></app-header>
      <app-home></app-home>
      <app-footer></app-footer>

    </div>  

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  @import '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900%7CRoboto:300,400,500,700,900';
  @import './assets/css/style.css';
  @import './assets/css/fonts.css';
</style>
```

Note:Only core.min.js file is imported in all vue files.

Image of project directory

[image]

Comment: This first thing I would try is removing `'jquery': path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')` from your webpack alias. Assuming a recent version of jquery, I would not expect that to be necessary.

Comment: removed same error.

Comment: Great. Now from your linked source code, I can see the error is coming from the minified source of jquery-form. Looks like you're using version 3.51. The latest on github is 4.2.2. Try upgrading.

Comment: Thank you bro the problem solved but i get another error in babel loader:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGEjg_4p8MeG0aH47n7z9GLI0Ye8B0Hy/view

Comment: Look at the error, it's coming from Footer.vue. You're not exporting anything from there.

Comment: ya it is fixed now .Thank you